# Search results don't show a preview of all of the matching terms

Tags: feature-request, search

Search results don't show a preview of each search term unless the terms all happen fortuitously to be in the question title or, apparently, close to each other.

For example, if I search for *search preview*, I see the image below.  **Notice how the fifth result only shows the context for *one* of the search terms.**

The problem is most noticeable if search results are sorted by something other than relevance.  If, on the same search, I switch to **vote** precedence, most of the top 50 results don't highlight *either* of the search terms, and none of them highlight both.

Is there a reason for this behavior?  It would be more useful if, for each result, I could see a snippet showing the context in which my search terms were matched.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

When you search for `search preview` you get results for **both** `search` and `preview` that is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Try searching for `"search preview"` and you might get what you want (which is *nothing*)

Comment: No, that's not what I'm searching for.  When I search for *search preview* without quotes, I want results that have the words *preview* and *search* in any order.  As far as I can tell, all of the results contain both words *somewhere*.  But the result view doesn't show me *where* they contain these words.  It only occasionally shows the context for one or both.

Comment: @Kyralessa All of those page ***have*** the other search term in them (in the answers). That is included in the search parameters.

Comment: You are correct, and I pointed that out in my previous comment.  My point is that I can't *see* that in the search results view.  My request is about seeing the context in which *each* search term matches, rather than the context for just one of the search terms, or even no context for *any* of them.

Comment: @Kyralessa There is always context, just not in the the shown image, but in the post at large, both of your words are there.

Comment: I'm not sure how much simpler I can make this, but let's give it one more shot.  If the question has "My name is Bob" and one (of many) answers has "I work in a button factory", then if I search for *bob button*, I'd want to see that question in the results, and *in the description below the question*, something like this: "My name is **Bob**....work in a **button** factory."  That would tell me what context both words occurred in, to help me figure out whether their use in that question and answer are relevant to my search or not.

Comment: Actually now that search does return one result.... this very question. :D